# python class Multiple inheritance __init__ object has no attribute 'xxx'

Tags: python-3.x

i have class , it inheritance other tow class.

```py
class Req(Proxy, Headers):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

class Proxy:
    pass

class Headers:
    def __init__(self):
        self.kdl_proxy_params = config.kdl_proxy_params

    def get_ua(self):
        res = requests.get("https://dev.kdlapi.com/api/getua", params=self.kdl_proxy_params).json()
        ua = res["data"]["ua_list"][0]
        return ua

r = Req()
r.get_ua()
```

So I received the following error message

```
AttributeError: 'Req' object has no attribute 'kdl_proxy_params'
```

I feel that this is a question of multiple inheritance. I hope you can help me to solve my doubts.

Comment: Hi  羊俊杰 , if you think the issue is with multiple inheritances, I suggest you make the classes very simple, just simple print statements in them, and try to see the issue.

Comment: Are you using Python2 or Python3 to run the code? What is that `config` in that `__init__` function? pay attention to those and make the code as simple as possible.

Comment: yes, I used single inheritance to solve the problem and make it look simpler

Comment: i'm use python3